# VLOOKUP in Python Pandas without using MERGE

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, vlookup

I have two DataFrames with one common column as the key and I want to perform a VLOOKUP sort of operation to fetch values from the first DataFrame corresponding to the keys in second DataFrame.

```
DataFrame 1
    key value
0   aaa 111
1   bbb 222
2   ccc 333
```

```
DataFrame 2
    key value
0   bbb None
1   ccc 333
2   aaa None
3   aaa 111
```

```
Desired Output
    key value
0   bbb 222
1   ccc 333
2   aaa 111
3   aaa 111
```

I do not want to use `merge` as both of my DFs might have `NULL` values for the key column and since pandas merge behave differently than sql join, all such rows might get joined with each other.

I tried below approach

```
DF2['value'] = np.where(DF2['key'].isnull(), DF1.loc[DF2['key'].equals(DF1['key'])]['value'], DF2['value'])
```

but have been getting `KeyError: False` error.

Comment: a merge is working fine: `DF2[['key']].merge(DF1, on='key', how='left')` so does `map`: `DF2['key'].map(DF1.set_index('key')['value'])`

Comment: @mozway yes, `merge` works fine in this case, however assume that we have 2 rows in DF1 that has key as NULL and additional 1 row in DF2 that has key as NULL. Now in this case my resultant DF will have 6 rows instead of 5 since DF2's NULL row will be mapped with both the NULL rows in DF1.
However, `map` seems a more feasible approach in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df2['value'] = df2['value'].fillna(df2['key'].map(df1.set_index('key')['value']))
print(df2)

# Output
   key value
0  bbb   222
1  ccc   333
2  aaa   111
3  aaa   111
```